# Object doesn't support this property or method<div ng-transclude>

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angularjs-directive

I am trying to develop a generic validation directive. My primary aim is to apply the directive on the input element's parent and using that directive, I want to add validation state like `has-error` and `has-success` classes provided by Bootstrap.

I am able to do this in chrome. However, my problems start with IE8. Yes, I am in hard luck. I have to support IE8.

Anyway, my code is able to transclude input element in appropriate location in template. However, I don't have a clue why this error is popping up in IE8 and at which line also. Error is

`TypeError: Object doesn't support this property or method<div ng-transclude>`

Here is my code, since it is just a demo which I am preparing right now, I have used inline styles and scripts.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myApp" id="ng-app">
<head>
    <title>All in One Validation Directive</title>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/angular.js"></script>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="styles/bootstrap.css"/>

    <script type="text/ng-template" id="validationContent">
        <div ng-transclude></div>
        <p class="bg-danger">{{errorMessage}}</p>
    </script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        var app=angular.module('myApp', []);

        app.controller('DefaultController', function($scope){
            $scope.user={};
        });

        app.directive('validationDirective', function(){
            return {
                restrict: 'A',
                /*template: function(){
                    return angular.element(document.querySelector('#validationContent')).html();
                },*/
                template: '<div ng-transclude></div>',
                transclude: true,
                link: function(scope, element, attrs){

                }
            };
        });
    </script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="DefaultController">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="panel panel-default">

            <div class="panel-heading">
                <h4>All in One Validation Directive</h4>
            </div>


            <div class="panel-body">
                <div class="form-horizontal">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="control-label col-xs-3">Enter Your Name</label>

                        <div class="col-xs-3" data-validation-directive>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="user.name">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            User Name is here :{{user.name}}
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

And if you believe that I am using wrong approach for this problem. Please suggest the right one.

**EDIT**

After some hit and trial, I am able to conclude that this is happening due to presence of input element in the divison to be transcluded. If I remove input element from that division, everything works fine but that is not the goal of the directive. Anyone ? Any Idea ? How I can sort it out ? Or may be I am in wrong direction ? Any clues ?

Comment: What version of angular are you using? Angular dropped IE8 support starting with version 1.3 and greater;

Comment: Sorry. I should have mentioned it. I am using 1.2.16.

Comment: Press f12 and see what version of IE that it is using or emulating. If it is using IE7 that might be your issue. To resolve, you could add the following in your <head> tag: <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">

Comment: It is using IE8 standards mode.
I tried adding your code into the page. It doesn't works. :(
Any idea why I am hitting this error ?

Comment: try using data-ng-transclude or data-ng:transclude

Comment: @DayanMorenoLeon: it doesn't helps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After a lot of break-points and **[Sarah's invaluable help](http://sarahbranon.com/post/63597186759/quick-tips-angularjs-debugging-in-ie8)**, it turned out it has to do with two things:

1. IE8's detecting (and not ignoring) the white-space after your `input`'s closing tag as an extra node (trying to append it to `div[ng-transclude]`.
2. JQLite's not proper handling of text-nodes (I am not exactly sure what is not handled properly, but I wasn't in the mood of investigating further :/).

---

Possible fixes:

1. Include jQuery: This solves the problem (and maybe other potential issues), but it is frustrating to have to include a whole lib, just to solve a corner-case issue with one version of one browser.
2. Make sure there are no white-space characters (spaces, tabs, new-lines) after your controls' closing tag. I am not sure which tags are affected (`<input>`, `<select>` and `<fieldset>` seem to be, but there may be others).
   You can either strip any white-space: `<input ... /></div>`
   or (if you want to retain the code structure, e.g. for readability's sake) you can "wrap" the white-space in a comment-block:

   ```
      <div>
          <input ... /><!--
   --></div>
   ```

---

See, also, this **[short demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ExpertSystem/86VRw/)**.

Comment: sorry I was not available at the moment to create plunker. By the time I opened plunker, you had done your magic.
Thanks. :)

Comment: @hasH: After I posted the comment, I noticed you had posted all necessary info, so it was just a matter of copy-paste :)

Comment: You can add `fieldset` to that list of problem tags!